# Getting most recent youtube video links for a user using API

Tags: javascript, html, api, video, youtube

So, I've been reading the Youtube API--I'm interested in showing the three most recent videos uploaded by a user. But, as I've never navigated an API or done this kind of work before, I'm a bit confused by what exactly [the API here is trying to tell me.](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Understanding_Video_Entries) What I DO understand is that if I enter a URL like the following:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/aosjeff/uploads

Then I'll get a ton of information in a kind of list. What I don't understand is how to navigate that list in HTML, and make it return a link to the most recent video (or second most recent, etc) so that I can embed that video into the page. Can anyone explain this to me? Really appreciate the help!

Note: I'm working within site building software that will not allow me to use PHP or reference .php files.

Simon

Comment: Any help on this? I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at parsing the xml data with php. This is probably the easiest way of doing things. Beginners tutorial here:

http://www.kirupa.com/web/xml_php_parse_beginner.htm

Comment: It's a good idea, but unfortunately, I can't use .php, because I can't upload or refer to .php files with the site-building software my company is already using, called squarespace. Is there any way to do it just in HTML, XML, or Javascript?

Comment: Yes, this can be done also in JavaScript. Link: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp