# Youtube API - Display most recently uploaded video from a specific user

Tags: youtube-api

I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time now. I am trying to Display most recently uploaded video from a specific user. First I tried doing It with `most_recent` (https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/GB/most_recent) etc.., but I soon realized that It is only able to get most recent video from a specific country, not user specific like I want. So the question is, what IS The url to get to user specific latest upload? All the google's pages about their API didn't mention a word about it(or I'm blind)
Pages I've read:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Standard_feeds
[Getting most recent youtube video links for a user using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484723/getting-most-recent-youtube-video-links-for-a-user-using-api)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use api version 2 instead of 3: Here is the documentation link:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos

The url to use is:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/uploads
;Where you replace userId, with the id of the specific user.

Use: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/uploads?max-results=1 , if only 1 result is needed.

Comment: Thanks mate! It's the simple things that come out as hard ones for me ^.^

Comment: Another question came out now, How do I Embed a video when It's like that? Cause the normal embedding won't work.

Comment: I would extract only the videoId from the response and then create the code to play the video. See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player

Comment: Sadly, api version 2 is "no longer available."

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to use Data API v3 instead of GData since it's the supported API. Support and new features will only come to Data API v3.

The way to do in v3 is, you first do a [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with part=contentDetails and mine=true to get authorized user's channel or id=USERS_CHANNEL_ID or forUsername = USERS_USERNAME

like `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

in the response you get [uploads playlist id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads) and put it into [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) call in "id" parameter

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&id={ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Uploads playlist is in order, so first result is the most recent upload. If you just want that result, in the call you can set maxResults=1

Comment: Good answer, but I cannot understand what I am supposed to do. What language do I have to use for it to work? That thing Is way too hard for me to understand at this stage. 
Cannot even understand what playlists you are talking about, since what I am trying to accomplish is to display the latest upload by that user. Is it really that complicated? D:

Comment: For anyone coming from Google looking for a solution, note that this does *not* guarantee seeing the most recently published video. I'm looking at an uploads playlist that is sorted properly on YouTube, however the API doesn't produce those videos in the same order. In fact, the playlist is showing a video from 5 days ago as being "most recent", while the channel in question has already uploaded another 8 videos...